# Sending Email using smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I have following code which successfully sent email using Gmail address. But when i tried to use email account other than Gmail which is one of domain email. It gaves me socket error. Do i need to change something?

```
def sendEmail(userName, password, subject, content, toEmail, fromEmail):
    print 'Sending email to: %s' % toEmail
    SMTPserver = 'smtp.gmail.com'

    sender =     fromEmail
    destination = [toEmail]

    USERNAME = userName
    PASSWORD = password

   text_subtype = 'plain'
   try:
       content = content
       subject = subject

       msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
       msg['Subject'] = subject
       msg['From']   = sender

       conn = SMTP(SMTPserver, 587)
       conn.ehlo()
       conn.starttls()
       conn.ehlo()

       conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
       try:
           conn.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())
           print 'Email sent successfully.'
       finally:
           conn.close()
   except Exception, exc:
       raise exc
```

The email which i am using  is `domains@smoothplus.com` . I also tried updating `SMTPserver = 'smtp.gmail.com'` to `SMTPserver = 'smtpout.secureserver.net'` the smptp of my domain but it also did not work. Please help.

Comment: what purpose has `except Exception, exc:
       raise exc`?

Comment: i was first saving the exception in error logger but for testing (where is the problem) i raise exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be You have to change `conn = SMTP(SMTPserver, 587)` port also with respective to your email server.

Comment: Right - 587 is for "outgoing servers" only, and is quite a "new invention". Traditionally, Port 25 was used for this, so maybe ypour provider's server doesn't support it (yet).

Comment: Tried it using `port 25` but got this error (short description) `SMTP Error: connect error 10060`

Comment: @Aamir Adnan Dot try any random setting its better to get the proper settings from your System admin who is managing your email server ,he can give you the correct Server nama and port numbers or other settings like ssl or something like need or not..

Comment: what information should i ask for from System admin? already got smtpserver address. Do i ask for port?

Comment: ok here is info `smtpout.secureserver.net  80, 3535, 25, 465 (SSL)` so it required SSL? then i used `from smtplib import SMTP_SSL` and i removed STARTTLS/EHLO commands. then it gives me error that said `run connect first`

Comment: Is there any way i use smtp of gmail and send email using email adress other than gmail? in other words a generic email sender program?

Answer (score 4):

When you use `SMTPserver='smtp.gmail.com'` try port number as 465, it may work.